# How to determine amount of available storage space on a blank DVD in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, iso, dvd, hp-ux

I was wondering if there was a way to determine the amount of space available in a blank writable DVD using a bash command.

Comment: Is it a writable DVD? Is the filesystem mounted as writable? Otherwise, the amount of space available is 0 bytes.

Comment: @John Watts: Yes, the DVD should be blank and writeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use dvd+rw-mediainfo out of dvd+rw-tools and parse its output?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I didn't know that this command existed.

Comment: An example of the output at:

http://www.mail-archive.com/cdwrite@other.debian.org/msg12507.html

Comment: Ack...I do not have enough reputation points to downvote...someone else must have done it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mount the DVD and use the `df` command this will show you the amount of free space for all devices.

If you'd like a more readable format you can also use `df -h`.